# Finding radius of convergence with the root test

Tags: calculus, limits, power-series

given the sum $S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)^{n^2}\frac{\left(2x+1\right)^n}{n}$ find the convergence radius

I tried finding it with the root test and Cauchy–Hadamard theorem but I got stuck, here is my attempt:

$S=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{n}2^n\left(x+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$  so our series is:

$a_n = \frac{\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{n}2^n$

$\lim _{n\to \infty }\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{\:\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{n}2^n\right)\:}=\:\lim _{n\to \infty }\left(2\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{\:\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)^{n^2}}{n}\right)\:}\right)\:=\lim _{n\to \:\infty \:}\left(2\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{\:\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)}{\sqrt[n^2]{n}}\right)^{n^2}\:}\right)= 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty \:}\left(2\left(\frac{\:\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)}{\sqrt[n^2]{n}}\right)^n\:\right)\:=\:\lim_{n\to \infty \:\:}\left(2\left(\frac{\:\left(1+\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n}\right)^n}{\sqrt[n]{n}}\right)\:\right)$

but from here I wasn't able to continue (tried using chain rule but it's dead-end). any idea what to do from here? maybe this isn't the right direction for the solution

Comment: You need to estimate $\limsup_n$ ($\lim_n$ does not exists here)See this wiki [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)

Comment: The sup here is tends to $\infty$?

Comment: No it does not. In your particular series, $\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{|a_n||2x+1|^n}=e|2x+1|$

Comment: How you calculate it?

Comment: $a_n=\frac1n\big(1+\tfrac{(-1)^n}{n}\big)^n$. Recall that $\sqrt[n]{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$. Notice that $\Big(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\Big)^n$ converges to $e^{-1}$ if $n\rightarrow\infty$ along odd numbers; and  $\Big(1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\Big)^n$  converges to $e$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ along even numbers.